# How to replace strings in list from a dictionary with all possible combinations

Tags: python, list

I want to replace a string named `test1` which is listed in lst using a dictionary named `gRep1Map`. It needs to return all possible combinations using the characters in `gRep1Map`. I get an output, but not the one i want to. Can't really seem to find a way how to achieve this.

Here is my code.

```
text = "Test1"

#Create dictionary
gReplMap = { 'a': '@', 'e': '3', 'i': '1', 'o': '0', 't': '+',
             'A': '@', 'E': '3', 'I': '1', 'O': '0', 'T': '+',
}

lst = []

for old, new in gReplMap.items():
    text = text.replace(old, new)
    lst.append(text)
    print(lst)
```

The output is like below.

```
['Test1']
['Test1', 'T3st1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3s+1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1']
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3st1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', 'T3s+1', '+3s+1']
```

But i want it to be like this.

```
['test1', 'tes+1', 't3st1', 't3s+1', '+est1', '+es+1', '+3st1', '+3s+1']
```

Anyone who could help?

Comment: print  list outside the loop.

Comment: Oh yeah correct, forgot about that.
But then i still get the wrong list of strings.
`['test1', 't3st1', 't3st1', 't3st1', '+3s+1', '+3s+1', '+3s+1', '+3s+1', '+3s+1', '+3s+1']`

Comment: how does `'test1'` (lowercase) would get produced from the initial `text = 'Test1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be iterating through the dictionary but through the letters of the text.  Here is a solution that doesn't use itertools.

```
text = "Test1"
gReplMap = { 'a': '@', 'e': '3', 'i': '1', 'o': '0', 't': '+',
         'A': '@', 'E': '3', 'I': '1', 'O': '0', 'T': '+'}
lst = [text]
#Iterate through each letter in each word in lst and update the lst
for string in lst:
    for letter in string:
        if letter in gReplMap:
            new_string = string.replace(letter, gReplMap[letter])
            if new_string not in lst:
                lst.append(new_string)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

(a rare case of usefulness of `reduce`...)

```py
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

out = {
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y[0], y[1]), repls, text)
    for n in range(len(gReplMap) + 1)
    for repls in combinations(gReplMap.items(), n)
}
```

Produces:

```py
>>> out
{'+3s+1', '+3st1', '+es+1', '+est1', 'T3s+1', 'T3st1', 'Tes+1', 'Test1'}
```

If you prefer to see the distinct values in the order they were generated, use a `dict` (which has insertion order) and make a list of it:

```
out = list({
    reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y[0], y[1]), repls, text): 1
    for n in range(len(gReplMap) + 1)
    for repls in combinations(gReplMap.items(), n)
})
```

Then:

```
>>> out
['Test1', 'T3st1', 'Tes+1', '+est1', 'T3s+1', '+3st1', '+es+1', '+3s+1']
```

Note: in the desired result of your original question, all the variants of `'test1'` seem lowercase, but neither your sample code or the text of the question seems to specify that. Of course, use `.lower()` after reduce if that's what you want.